# admob_flutter Flutter package causing error in Debug mode only

Tags: flutter

I have been using the `admob_flutter` package. I was able to successfully debug and run with this package installed. However, it suddenly gives me this error now:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

The project is able to build and display ads successfully. The error comes up when I'm running debug mode. I have tried:

- running `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`.
- Deleting the `.gradle` folder.
- Deleting the current instance of the Flutter SDK and installing a new instance of the same verison.
- Reinstalling the package and downgrading.

None of the above steps have helped. What could be the issue?

Comment: may I know the flutter version that used right? Try to upgrade your flutter version to latest version and switch the channel to the stable version.

Comment: @khoi I am using Flutter 2.2.0 and Dart 2.13.0.. I am running on the latest version of flutter

Comment: I have tried switching the channel to the stable version and have also upgraded Dart. Still gives the same issue

Comment: if you still get the same issues, open android studio/Xcode and see msg on the log or compile the project from android studio/Xcode. some error does not show on flutter. Try getting a clear error message instead of the current error that you're provided.

Comment: I've managed to solve it last week, by reinstalling the project.